# Select tag which meets a condition

Tags: html, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm quite new in css selectors and I'm trying to do this:

I have a `html` with multiple `div`s. I want to select the first `div` meeting some condition, let's say `div[id*='ample']` and then, select all `div`s with the same condition, but not the first `div`s children.

```
<div id="example1">
    <div id="example2">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="example3">
</div>
```

So the thing I want is to get the `div` whose `id='example1'` and `id='example3'`. 
The best would be if for example the `div` with `id='example3'` doesn't have to be the first `div`s brother.

Do you know how to do that?

I was thinking about:

```
div = css_select("div[id*='ample')")
while True: 
   divs.append(div)
   div = div + css_select("div[id*='ample')")
```

But it's probably worthless.

Comment: You should avoid using id's for this purpose, they are not meant to work this way, consider using classes (you probably know this)

Comment: You should have edited this question instead of [reposting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295473/find-tags-using-css-selector-but-not-their-descendants).

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to select elements in JavaScript, it's depends on the html.

Back to your question: you can do it by using the parent of those divs (the `body` for example)

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;


/* 'body > *[id*="ample"]' - you can replace the 'body' selector with other parent selector */
document.querySelectorAll('body > *[id*="ample"]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add('red');
});
```

```css
div {
  height:10px;  
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.red {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
    <div id="example2">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="example3">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since the div don't has to be a child of body, it could be grandchild etc.