# Find tags using css selector but not their descendants

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to find tags meeting some condition but just those on the **first level (relatively)** (not their **children** etc.). I don't want to find their **children**, **grandchildren** etc. whose meeting the condition. Is it possible?

I'm using **Selenium** with **Python**

```
<div id="example1">
    <div id="example2">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="example3">
</div>
```

I want to return `example1` and `example3` (not `example2`).

Those `div`s can be a children of a `body` but they can be also grandchildren etc. so `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(body > div[name*=example])` is not enough.

Comment: Need more info on the HTML around the elements that you want. What is the parent element of example1 & 3? etc. How can you tell which elements that you want?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
*:not([id*=example]) > [id*=example]
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVxYjE